# SpringXD - It is possible to scan different dirs via File source?

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I've these dirs

```
|- Dad Dir
     |--- Son Dir 1
             |---- file1.txt
             |---- file2.txt
     |--- Son Dir 2
             |---- file3.txt
```

it is possibile with a single stream, using the `File Source`, extrapolate the contents of `file*.txt` for example, giving in the input `Dad Dir`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with the standard source, but you can customize the source to use a `WatchServiceDirectoryScanner` (java 7 or later) or `RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner` which is not recommended for large directory trees.

See the [Spring Integration Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-reading) for information about configuring the file inbound channel adapter. Use the `scanner` attribute on the adapter.